# ¿Como migrar los datos de una bases de datos SQL a otra?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, backend

En mi trabajo me pidieron que haga una nueva base de datos ya que la anterior es un desastre, casi termino la nueva base de datos pero tambien me pidieron que migre los datos que estaban guardados en la antigua base de datos SQL a la nueva base de datos SQL, estoy usando mysql workbench.

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que la base de datos nueva tenga campos adicionales que la base de datos antigua no tenga, yo haría lo siguiente:

1. Crear una base de datos nueva con todas sus tablas y su correspondiente relación (`FOREIGN KEYS` etc). **Ya lo tienes hecho**.
2. Programar un script que recorriendo todos los registros de tu base de datos antigua, los inserte en tu base de datos nueva, quedándome solamente con los campos que me interesen. Ten en cuenta que después de hacer este paso tendrás `n` filas en tu tabla y dichas filas tendrán campos en blanco. Estos campos en blanco son las nuevas columnas que te faltarían por rellenar con la nueva información que no existía en la base de datos antigua.
3. Programaría otra función en mi script que cargue la información restante en la nueva base de datos partiendo de la fuente de datos en la que tengas los datos que te faltan por cargar (por ejemplo un csv).

Comment: el unico lenguaje que se que me puede ayudar es php ¿conoces alguna libreria que haga eso por mi? muchas gracias por tu aporte me ayudo bastante.

Comment: No creo que exista una librería que lo haga. Ten en cuenta que estás creando una base de datos nueva con una relación de datos distinta a la que ya tienes, por lo que la carga de datos tendrás que importarla siguiendo tu nueva jerarquía.